# How to download dictionary from url?

Tags: python, json, pandas, url

I would like to download the dictionary from the following url: https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000320193.json

The reason for that is because I would like to extract some datas from the dict into a pandas df. It should look like this:

```
filed_date   filed_periode   form    accn
2020-11-01   Q4              10-K    0001193125-15-153166
2020-08-01   Q3              10-Q    0001193125-15-153112
```

I could extract a dict from another SEC-link by using following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import json

url1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json'

sec_dict = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
for line in sec_dict:
    decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")
company_dict = json.loads(decoded_line)
```

If used the above code for the 1st url, I'll get the following error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I have tried another following approach but get the same error:

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000320193.json"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
```

Thank you in advance for any pointer :-)

Comment: In general, *forbidden* means what it says. The website is blocking your request. Some sites do not welcome programmatic access and go to some lengths to stop you doing it. Or it may be that your code made too many requests in a short space of time and you hit some limit.

Comment: That user-agent you're trying (Firefox 3, from 2009) has been so widely used by automated tools that it's also banned by SEC's automated security. (Also, please read the response you get with the Forbidden response. It explains all this.) Try something else.

Comment: Looks like the error you're getting is about the use of automated tools: https://jsfiddle.net/dyb0sjr2/

Comment: gotta spoof better to get the goods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SEC has an unusual requirement for user agent strings. They want it to be in the format `Sample Company Name AdminContact@<sample company domain>.com`

So for me, a compliant user agent would be:

```
user_agent = 'Dan Monego <myemail>@<emailservice>'
```

Change the user agent to include your name and email.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. Do you happen to have a short guide to download datas from SEC? Is there any good webpage for that? Thank you in advance

Comment: There's a short guide here: https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data